# Node JSHint use one config file for all

Tags: node.js, jshint

I have installed node.js with JSHint npm. I need to configure settings for it. I have a .jshintrc file created.

Is it possible to have JSHint run this .jshintrc file everytime? I know I can set a --config flag when calling jshint from the command line or I can add it the route of my project directory. But is possible to have it use this config everytime I call JSHint? Just have the config file in one location and that's it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of .jshintrc, JSHint will start looking for this file in the same directory as the file that's being linted. If not found, it will move one level up the directory tree all the way up to the filesystem root. (Note that if the input comes from stdin, JSHint doesn't attempt to find a configuration file)
So just omit the --config flag and place the .jshintrc for example in your home directory /home/user/.jshintrc. If Your Project is located at /home/user/projects/priojecta/lib/file.js it will work

Comment: Yep, that is what I thought. I just have the .jshintrc in a folder. I was hoping I could modify JSHint to run this config by default but I guess I'll just have remember to use --config whenever I'm running it. Thanks for your help!